# How to put a npm global cli tool on homebrew?

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew

How my cli tool is currently installed:

`$ npm install -g <my cli tool>`

I want to put my tool on homebrew so that I can do the following:

`$ brew install <my cli tool>`

I've read the homebrew cookbook for creating your own formulas, and I've also looked at other example formulas, but I'm still quite confused with the syntax as I'm not familiar with ruby. Are there any example formulas of placing a simple npm global package on homebrew that I can follow?